# Can I use a single ADFS server for both office 365 and SharePoint SSO

Tags: sharepoint-2010, adfs

Can I use a single ADFS server for both office 365 and SharePoint SSO if they use different SSL's and domain names?

Enviroment consists of:

2 DC's --
ADFS Server --
ADFS Proxy --
Sharepoint 2010 Server (portal.companyname.com) --
hosted o365 (companynameMail.com)

o365 SSO is currently working flawlessly (after a LOT of work) I want to add SSO for our SharePoint server.

I'm unclear if its possible, and stuck at adding in a second SSL on the ADFS server.

(And yes, I will be adding redundent servers as time and budget permits)

Comment: Your question isnt very clear. You mention "adding a second SSL" on ADFS and then in the comment you mention SharePoint too. Its not clear whether you want a Yes/No answer to know if its possible to achieve what you are trying to do. Or whether you need specific help on ADFS or SharePoint or both in configuring this setup. The more detail you provide explaining exactly what you have, what you have done and what you need help with will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem here. I have a lab environment where my AD FS 2.0 is used for many relying parties including O365 and a SP2010 server.

Are you asking if its possible to use the existing ADFS infrastructure used for O365 with the on-premise SharePoint 2010 implementation? Yes thats possible. You will end up with two relying party trusts (one for O365 and the other for SP2010).

Edit 28/12:
I assume you know how to configure SP2010 for federated authentication. Please see http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx as it should help.

Comment: by second SSL I mean an additional SSL certificate for the SP server